# Passing two different arguments to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written some jQuery functions, and recently realized I needed to reuse the code for another situation. I refactored the code to accept a selector as an arguement, so I can now use for case 1, and case 2. However, when I execute my functions in `document.ready` I get weird results.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    imageCalc('.com-background > img');
    setImageDims('.com-background > img', '#main-content');
    imageCalc('.blog-entry-content iframe');
    setImageDims('.blog-entry-content iframe', '#content');
});
```

It should be noted, these selectors do no show up on the same page. Also, when I only run one instance of `imageCalc()` and `setImageDims()` These functions work just fine. Here are the functions in question..

```
function imageCalc(selector) {
    var obj=$(selector);
    $imgWidth = obj.width();
    $imgHeight = obj.height();
    $imgAspectRatio =  $imgHeight / $imgWidth;
    // $(selector).css('margin-left', function( calcMargin ) { return parseInt($('.main-content').css('padding')) * -1 + "px"; }); fix for ie
    obj.css('margin-left', '-10px' );

}
function setImageDims(selector, content_area) {
    var container = $(content_area);
    $(selector).css('height', function() { return $imgAspectRatio * container.width(); });
    $(selector).css('width', function() { return container.width() + 20; });    
}
```

In summary, all the code works just fine, when I only have each function called only ONCE in `document.ready` but I need to use this code for 2 scenarios, how can I do this?

Comment: Can you include a demo showing those "weird results"?

Comment: Where do you declare the variables $imgWidth, $imgHeight and $imgAspectRatio?  Can you give the full example of the code?

Answer (score 4):

Add a `var` in front of your `$imgWidth`, `$imgHeight`, and `$imgAspectRatio` variables. Without the `var`, they're being declared at global scope, and therefore accidentally getting shared across both calls to that function.

UPDATE: I just noticed that the `$imgAspectRatio` is being used by both functions. Perhaps you can make that the return value from the first function, so it can be passed into the second function.

To elaborate... something like this should theoretically work, although I'm not able to test it since I don't have the corresponding HTML:

```
function imageCalc(selector) {
    var obj=$(selector);
    var $imgWidth = obj.width();
    var $imgHeight = obj.height();
    var $imgAspectRatio =  $imgHeight / $imgWidth;
    // $(selector).css('margin-left', function( calcMargin ) { return parseInt($('.main-content').css('padding')) * -1 + "px"; }); fix for ie
    obj.css('margin-left', '-10px' );
    return $imgAspectRatio;
}
function setImageDims(selector, content_area, $imgAspectRatio) {
    var container = $(content_area);
    $(selector).css('height', function() { return $imgAspectRatio * container.width(); });
    $(selector).css('width', function() { return container.width() + 20; });    
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var ratio1 = imageCalc('.com-background > img');
    setImageDims('.com-background > img', '#main-content', ratio1);
    var ratio2 = imageCalc('.blog-entry-content iframe');
    setImageDims('.blog-entry-content iframe', '#content', ratio2);
});
```

Comment: The fiddle above is to illustrate how the apsect ratio still doesn't seem to compute

Comment: Nice! I see the doggy in the grass. It appears to have the same ratio as the original (http://viralstash.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/521013543_1385596410.jpg). What is computing incorrectly?

Comment: Okay, So I think I've narrowed it down.. the imageCalc() and setImageDims() are fine now, but on the resize() function we need to pass ratio1 (or ratio2) to imageResize()

Comment: Hmmm... this is slightly hackish, but one approach we've used in the past for this sort of thing was to assign the calculated value (the image ratio in this case) to an attribute on the element in question. That way, given the element's selector later, you can use it to grab and reuse the earlier calculated value. Does that make sense? Something like `obj.attr('data-ratio', $imgAspectRatio);` before the `return` statement in `imageCalc` to set it, and then read it via `obj.attr('data-ratio')` in `setImageDims` later. Let me know if you want me to fork the fiddle with that tweak...

Comment: BTW, this is probably obvious, but if you use the "stash the ratio in an attribute on the element" approach, you won't need the return value and extra parameter that I suggested earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62780/discussion-between-chris-and-troy-gizzi).

Answer (score 0):

This will require you to re-work your functionsas `setImageDims` depends on `$imgAspectRatio` to be available globally.

```
function imageCalc(selector) {
    var obj=$(selector),
        $imgWidth = obj.width(),
        $imgHeight = obj.height(),
        $imgAspectRatio =  $imgHeight / $imgWidth;
    // $(selector).css('margin-left', function( calcMargin ) { return parseInt($('.main-content').css('padding')) * -1 + "px"; }); fix for ie
    obj.css('margin-left', '-10px' );

    return $imgAspectRatio;
}

function setImageDims(selector, content_area) {
    var container = $(content_area);
    $(selector).css('height', function() { return imageCalc(selector) * container.width(); });
    $(selector).css('width', function() { return container.width() + 20; });    
}
```

Comment: Tristan Lee, I've added a fiddle to illustrate how the aspect ratio still doesn't seem to calculate http://jsfiddle.net/aauodyby/